# Optimizing C# memory allocation

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, monogame

I ran into a rather peculiar thing today when trying to optimize. I use the Monogame framework and want to create textures on the fly. I use .NET 6 in Visual Studio Community 2022.

So this is the straightforward code for doing this, which is working fine:

```
    public static Texture2D CreateTexture(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, int width, int height)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new(graphicsDevice, width, height, true, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        Color color = new((byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255);
        int length = width * height;
        Color[] colorArray = new Color[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            color.A = (byte)randomizer.Next(0, 256);
            colorArray[i] = color;
        }

        tex.SetData<Color>(colorArray);

        return tex;

    }
```

Since I call this method many times, usually with the same width and height, I thought I could do some memory optimizations, and ended up with the similar code:

```
    static int texW = 1;
    static int texH = 1;
    static Color[] colorArray = new Color[1];

    public static Texture2D CreateTexture2(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, int width, int height)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new(graphicsDevice, width, height, true, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        int length = width * height;

        if (texW != width || texH != height)
        {
            texW = width;
            texH = height;
            colorArray = new Color[length];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            colorArray[i].A = (byte)randomizer.Next(0, 256);
            colorArray[i].R = 255;
            colorArray[i].G = 255;
            colorArray[i].B = 255;
        }

        tex.SetData<Color>(colorArray);

        return tex;
    }
```

As you see I try to avoid allocating the `colorArray` each time the function is called. Since the array is a list of Color-struct-objects I assumed I should replace the R,G,B and A values in each struct object with new rather than replacing the entire struct.

For testing it out I tried to call these two functions a few thousand times a second for about thirty seconds each, in separate debug sessions.

I expected my changes to improve various memory-related things, but no! Instead, my second example really upset the garbage collector which started to do frequent GCs, visual studios 'Diagnostic Tools' show about twice as many allocated objects and the framerate seems to drop as well.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on here? My second code example allocates the `colorArray` *one* time, as expected when I call it thousands of times with the same width and height. Also, assigning a value to the R,G,B and A members, which are of byte-type should not cause any memory allocations.

---

EDIT:

As Jeremy pointed out in the comments, it was `Texture2D` that was the culprit. I did not call `Dispose()` on the texture after drawing it in my test code.

Now when I call `Dispose()` the code works as expected. But I am a bit surprised about the small difference between the two pieces of code; Why is the first piece of code not upsetting the GC more than it does? In my simple test, I see no real difference.

---

EDIT 2:

Just to complete the case, I updated my code to use `tex.SetData()` (thanx Strom!) instead of creating a new `Texture2D` and then `Dispose()` each loop. Better results. But! I *still* get the peculiar difference where the framerate is better if I don't use a static `colorArray`. Without looking at the compiled code (intermediate language?) my only guess is that the compiler makes better optimizations in the code than I can do...

Comment: Is `Texture2D` a class? How much memory does it allocate?

Comment: Are you doing any benchmarks with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet)? The debugger is great and all but you want to benchmark your compiled and optimised code. Use the `MemoryDiagnoser` as well do see how much you're allocating. Create 2 benchmarks, one benching your original implementation and the other benching your latest implementation.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that attempting to test the impact of a single optimisation, ignored the elephant in the room. I didn't ask due to a lack of knowledge, but as a prompt for the OP to consider the rest of the function.

Comment: Jeremy, no offense taken! Thanks for your input, I learn something new every day and that makes me happy. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your Color data array from the Texture2D.

The Texture2D maintains memory links to the video card and should not be created every step. The other side of this statement is that Texture2D's should not be destroyed within the program outside of `UnLoadContent` or the class destructor.

Create the texture once:

```
// Class level variable
Texture2D tex;

// in Initialize()
// replace width and heigh with actual values.
tex = new(graphicsDevice, width, height, true, SurfaceFormat.Color);
```

Your original code had no benefit over the later one, I did modify it to save  a memory read per loop by generating a new Color struct each loop. Changing any member of a struct creates a new struct(value type semanitics).

The only improvement would be to pin the array in an unsafe context to eliminate the the two memory reads for offset and bounds checks on each access, but that is a different question.

```
public static Color[] CreateTexture(int width, int height)
    {
        int length = width * height;
        Color[] colorArray = new Color[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            color[i] = New Color((byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)255, (byte)randomizer.Next(0, 256));
        }
        return colorArray;
    }
```

Then during Update:

```
       tex.SetData<Color>(CreateTexture(tex.Width,tex.Height));
```

Comment: Thanx Strom, this improved the framerate as well. Turns out its much better using SetData() instead of creating and disposing the Texture2D each loop.